# Check network connection with LocationManager in Android

Tags: android, networking, gps, connection, location

I would like to check the network connection with the LocationManager in Android.
My code works fine with Galaxy SII and Version 4.0.3.
But it does not work with Galaxy S and Version 2.3.6.

The code:

```
 isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
 isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

I am connected to a Wi-Fi network for sure. But the if statement

```
if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
```

returns true. Are there known bugs and is there a reliable way to check it?

Comment: Location Providers and network [connectivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) are different things. One tells you whether the user has gps / network location tracking enabled in the system settings, the other one tells you whether you are connected to the internets.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out:**

```
    //If you only want to check your Internet connection available or not    
        public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();}
```

**Note**: `wifiInfo` provide you status about your **Wifi**, still it will be there poor connection I think it will good if make **HTTP reuest**, for more details check link provided.

**Edit**:
For more information you can [refer this][1].

Answer (score 0):

I am using below code in my every android project.
It will check for any active network that are used for outgoing connection.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 public static boolean checkConn(Context ctx)
{

    ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobileInfo = conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);    
    NetworkInfo info = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(info != null && info.isConnected()) {  
        Log.v("NetworkInfo","Connected State");  
        return true;
    }  
    return false;
}
```